# Google spreadsheet formula with conditions for array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I would like to find the right formula to see how the category of accounts changed over time. There are 2 tables: List - contains account id, start date, end date, current category, and date columns Status Change - contains account id, transfer date, changed from, changed to. I need to find the right formula for date columns in the List tab. It should work in this way:

1. If there is only a start date for the account and there are no
   records for this account in the Status Change tab, the current
   status should be the same for all periods till today.
2. If there is an end date for the account, the status should be empty after his date.
3. If there are records for an account in the Status Change tab, the
   status should be reflected accordingly in the List tab.

Here is the example table - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yw3t7oiuRUcWkzCuEB-20sMcnwOnt3BTmS7jjEdphIQ/edit#gid=1693652082

List tab contains the result that should be returned by formula.

Comment: hello there, i am not sure i understand what is your end goal here, as @LucasLui888 seems to yield the results you were looking for; can you provide more info on "The status should be substituted from the Status Change tab" & "tab format should not be changed either"?

Comment: Hi @ale13,
Originally, only A:D columns were on this tab. F:H were added by LucasLui888. 
Thus, my goal is to get the right status per month for each ID, based on the table with status changes. Status can be different, so the format of F:H columns doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you willing to accept a script solution for this?

Comment: The right formula is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Hey to achieve your intended goal from "List" tab, it will be an extremely complicated set of if else conditions:

```
=if($D2="",if(E$1<$C2,"", ifna(if(index('Status Change'!$G$2:$G,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0))="","Status 1", if(E$1<index('Status Change'!$G$2:$G,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0)),"Status 1",if(index('Status Change'!$H$2:$H,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0))="","Status 2",if(E$1<index('Status Change'!$H$2:$H,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0)),"Status 2","Status 3")))),"Status 1")),if(E$1<$D2,if(E$1<$C2,"", ifna(if(index('Status Change'!$G$2:$G,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0))="","Status 1", if(E$1<index('Status Change'!$G$2:$G,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0)),"Status 1",if(index('Status Change'!$H$2:$H,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0))="","Status 2",if(E$1<index('Status Change'!$H$2:$H,match($A2,'Status Change'!$F$2:$F,0)),"Status 2","Status 3")))),"Status 1")),""))
```

I have appended the formula into the "List Test" tab. Try to read up on what I have wrote and let me know if you have trouble understanding it. Thx

Comment: Thanks,
This is not exactly what I need. The status should be substituted from the Status Change tab, not specified in the formula. And tab format should not be changed either.

Comment: Hey @MaksymKatsovets sorry about that.

Regarding the status change, it is changing based on the Status Change tab. Basically the formula helps to read off the date to change before status and changes it according to the month.

Comment: Hi @LucasLui888. Status can be different, so the format of F:H columns doesn't work for me. It's important to use A:D columns only.